# New to asp. Problems connecting to database. Not sure about correct method to use

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been using asp forms for the past week or so. Mostly I've been getting used to gridview and using the site.master to display menus on each page and using the connectionstring in web.config to access my sql server database.

But I'm not finding gridview all that versatile and am a little confused as to how this is all supposed to work. I've come from PHP and ASP seems a world different. What I want to do is to loop a table and print out records but i want to use my own loop and not gridview so i can have custom columns as well. so i can create dynamic links with different gets and things like that. In PHP there was syntax to connect to the DB, write the loop and then print the html inside it by echoing or something like that.

In aspx I am using C# as my language so am I to understand that i literally write c# code in between <% --code-- %> for this to happen

So asp is basically an abiltiy to script using c# or VB

Lastly should I write the DB connection in code behinds Page_load or just at the top of the aspx file...

Sorry about the newbie question, I would really appreciate being pointed to a suitable tutorial as well which explains all this if anyone can help. I found the w3schools stuff which I usually use to be quite confusing.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? there is a free express version http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express . it makes it easier to create button on click events etc. in the code behind file. that seperates the markup (html) from the C# code. and second: you can bind a dataset or datatable to the gridview and have custom columns and/or edit templates etc. but if you want to do it manually, you can with a datalist or even repeater.

Comment: yeah, I'm using visual studio. Im coding in code behind. What I'm trying to figure out is how do i script html in the actual aspx file

Comment: don't try to build html as string in the code behind. bind a datatable or dataset to the gridview. and modify the gridview to have custom columns etc. maybe post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Grid view can be really powerful if used correctly, one of the things you can do is hook onto an event (on data row bound) which will allow you to manipulate each row at a time.

ASP.NET is more event driven than PHP, however if you still want to do things the PHP way you could in theory loop through each result.

```
  using (
           var oConn =
               new SqlConnection(
                   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionStringNameFromWebConfig"].ConnectionString)
           )
        {
            oConn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                oCmd.CommandText = "p_jl_GetThemeForPortal";
                oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@gClientID", clientID));
            }

             using(var oDR = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(oDR.Read())
                    {
                        string x = (string)oDR["ColumnName"];
                        int y = (int) oDR["ColumnName2"];
                        // Do something with the string and int
                    }
                }

        }
```

This pattern (by using using statements) ensures your connections are closed at the end of each fetch sequence, so you don't have lots of open DB connections kicking around

Comment: As a note, if you don't use a using statement then everything should be in a Try...Catch block and you should add a Finally statement where you check all of your readers and connections and close them if they are still open. Just another way to ensure all connections have been closed regardless of what happens. Using will do that automatically though with no extra code.

Comment: Thanks... So should I write this in the aspx file or in the code behind... Also am i right in saying that with your code above i can just say something like  Response.Write oDR("info")

Comment: @user967797 - do not use Response.Write (from the codebehind), the text will end up in the wrong place. You can add a Literal control and set it's Text property.

Answer (score 1):

first: Write your code on server side on Page_load or in any other method for selecting 
record.
and for selecting record from database you can use the following code

```
string myConnectionString="server=dbserver;database=mydatabase;uid=user;pwd=password;Connect Timeout=120;pooling=true;Max Pool Size=60;";// you can place your connection string in web.config
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT [stuff] FROM [tableOfStuff]";

con.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = null;
try
{
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        // construct your html for your table data here
    }
}
catch(SomeTypeOfException ex){ /* handle exception */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

For more control over the rendering, you can use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview). Scroll down to the bottom of that page for an example.

Answer (score 0):

example aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flag" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='<%# "img/flags/" + Eval("CountryFlag").ToString()%>' alt="flag" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="dg_title"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VAT" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# CheckBool(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CalculateVat"))) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

in the code behind the `CheckBool` is a function I have made:

```
public string CheckBool(bool toCheck)
{
    if (toCheck)
        return "<img src=\"img/checked.png\" alt=\"Yes\" />";
    else
        return "<img src=\"img/deleted.png\" alt=\"No\" />";
}
```

and in the `Page_Load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SsUtils.GetCountries();
    GridView1.DataBind();        
}
```

`SsUtils` is a static class and the `GetCountries` returns a `List<Country>` which is a collection of the class country. But you can also use a `DataSet` or `DataTable` as datasource for your gridview.

This is just a sample, to show some possibilities. You can also have edit buttons, paging, sorting etc. with a gridview.